# Yii The directory does not exist: /app/API/assets PHP

Tags: php, yii2

I make website in PHP YII framework.
I trying to hostin Heroku.
Its show error
[image]

how to solve it....

Comment: Please provide the error as plain text.

Comment: Have you tried creating the directory to see what happens then?

Comment: Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
The directory does not exist: /app/api/config/../../assets/AppAsset.php
1. in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.phpat line 213
    /**
     * @throws InvalidConfigException if [[basePath]] does not exist.
     */
    public function init(){        
parent::init();
        $this->basePath = Yii::getAlias($this->basePath);
        if (!is_dir($this->basePath)) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("The directory does not exist: {$this->basePath}");
        }
         $this->basePath = realpath($this->basePath);

Comment: The directory does not exist: /app/api/assets same erorr show

Comment: Please read [ask] and create [mcve] maybe posting your configuration file